# Можно ли неявно получить ссылку на класс из которого был вызван конструктор другого класса?

Tags: c#, .net

Допустим, есть класс, который вызывает в методе конструктор и создает тип.

Можно ли неявно в конструкторе класса получить ссылку на класс без явной передачи `this` в конструктор?

Пример:

```
 public class A
 {
     public void MethodA()
     {
         var b = new B();
     }
 }

 public class B
 {
     public B()
     {
         // каким-то образом неявно получаем ссылку на класс, который вызвал конструктор. 
         // Т.е в данном случае ссылка на экземпляр A
     }
 }
```

Если не ошибаюсь, то в `IL` в качестве первого аргумента всегда неявно передается ссылка на вызывающий код.

**P.S** Задач никаких нету. Интереса ради.

Comment: ничего непонятно:) попробуй пример кода добавить

Comment: @Grundy, добавил.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Нет, вы не можете получить экземпляр вызывающего класса. Этой информации нету даже на уровне IL. Конструктор `B`, декомпилированный в ILDasm, выглядит так:

```msil
.method public hidebysig specialname rtspecialname 
        instance void  .ctor() cil managed
{
  // Размер кода:       9 (0x9)
  .maxstack  8
  IL_0000:  ldarg.0
  IL_0001:  call       instance void [mscorlib]System.Object::.ctor()
  IL_0006:  nop
  IL_0007:  nop
  IL_0008:  ret
} // end of method B::.ctor
```

У него нету объявления параметров, так что скрытых параметров нету.

---

То, что вы можете выяснить — это какой конкретно метод вас вызывает, без указания на экземпляр класса. Это делается так:

```
[MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.NoInlining)]
public B()
{
    MethodBase callingMethod = new StackFrame(1).GetMethod();
    Console.WriteLine($"Called from type: {callingMethod.DeclaringType.FullName}, " +
                      $"calling method name: {callingMethod.Name}");
}
```

У меня выводит:

```
Called from type: Test.A, calling method name: MethodA
```

Вы создаёте stack frame, начинающийся на 1 выше вашего текущего фрейма, и запрашиваете метод. Имея reflection-дескриптор метода, вы можете получить информацию из него.

Заметьте, что я применил атрибут `MethodImplOptions.NoInlining`, чтобы запретить встраивать этот метод в точку вызова, в противном случае в stack trace могла бы попасть не та информация.

Ещё один немаловажный момент: запрос `StackFrame` — затратная, дорогостоящая операция, поэтому не стоит применять это решение в production-коде. Если вы хотите информацию о том. кто вас вызвал, в production-коде, стоит доверить это компилятору и воспользоваться атрибутом `[CallerMemberName]`, доступным начиная с .NET 4.5:

```
public B([CallerMemberName] string callerName = null,
         [CallerFilePath] string callerFile = null,
         [CallerLineNumber] int callerLineNumber = -1)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Called from method: {callerName}, " + 
                      $"located {callerFile}@{callerLineNumber}");
}
```

Выводит:

```
Called from method: MethodA, located D:\full path here\Test\Program.cs@42
```

Comment: А в самом стеке нельзя порыться, чтобы инстанс найти?

Comment: @Qwertiy: Интернет не знает способа. То есть наверное можно залезть в нативный код и найти нужный параметр в стеке, но я что-то сомневаюсь, что это поддерживаемый сценарий.

Comment: @VladD, мне кажется уже был практически идентичный вопрос