# Как определить, из какой формы была открыта текущая?

Tags: c#, winforms

Из одной формы запускается другая при помощи подобного кода (по сути, стандартного):

```
private void Show_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Child form1 = new Child();
        form1.ShowDialog();
    }
```

Как узнать тип той формы, которая запустила `Child`? На основе этого должно определяться содержимое формы `Child`.

Comment: Старайтесь придерживаться одно-направленного потока информации: форма/класс, которая создает `Child` знает про `Child`, а `Child` не знает про форму/класс, которая его создает. Что будет, если `Child` создается в методе класса, который не является формой? Подавайте в конструктор класса `Child`, или устанавливайте как его свойство, индикатор поведения `Child`.

Comment: @Igor, т. е. вы предлагаете просто отправлять нек. информацию в `Child`, а при инициализации `Child`'а её использовать?

Comment: да, я это предлагаю :)

Comment: Верно вам говорят, и вот смотрите, у вас есть метод `Show_Click`, в который параметрами передается объект и аргументы события. Если очень надо, то можете передавать в вашу форму данные через конструктор, а затем использовать его примерно так: `Child form1 = new Child(MyDataStruc Data);`, где `MyDataStruc` - это структура/класс с нужными вам данными. Или просто передаёте ссылку на родителя. Но тут тоже есть свои нюансы.

Comment: А еще есть вот такая [ссылка](http://melfis.ru/%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%8B-%D0%BD%D0%B0-7-%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BC%D1%8B%D1%85-%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8B%D1%85-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D0%BE-winforms/) на статью. Там пунктом 2 рассматривается передача данных из одной формы в другую. Целых 7 способов. Указаны как плюсы, так и минусы.
Итого, если у вас в дочерней форме окажутся сведения о родительской, то ваша задача решена, стало быть.

Comment: Можно попробовать через StackFrame, как писал VladD в том ответе, но это все таки неправильно,https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/612354/%D0%9C%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%8F%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%81%D1%81%D1%8B%D0%BB%D0%BA%D1%83-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%B1%D1%8B%D0%BB-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80-%D0%B4%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ну раз @VladD считает не зазорным ответ с "отлупом" :)

Старайтесь придерживаться одно-направленного потока информации: форма/класс, которая создает `Child` знает про `Child`, а `Child` не знает про форму/класс, которая его создает.

(Что будет, если `Child` создается в методе класса, который не является формой?  Подумаем.)

Подавайте в конструктор класса `Child`, или устанавливайте как его свойство, индикатор поведения `Child`.

Answer (score 3):

Никак.

В C# нету легального метода узнать, кто вызвал данный код. Даже если бы это было можно, это плохая практика: это не поддаётся ни рефакторингу, ни тестированию.

Пусть код, показывающий форму, сам конфигурируете её, передавая ей нужную информацию. В худшем случае это может быть просто `this`, в лучшем — специализированная структура данных, описывающая то, что нужно показать.

Ещё более хорошим вариантом является вынесение бизнес-логики (при каких обстоятельствах нужно открыть новое окно, и что за информацию в нём показывать) из UI-кода (кода исходной формы), но это скорее всего потребует большой переработки проекта.